# Binding to element within a TabControl's DataTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, datatemplate, tabcontrol, contentpresenter

Currently I'm having a problem with binding to an element that resides in a TabControl's DataTemplate.

The TabControl's works perfectly and displays the word 'Test'. The element I'd like to bind to is the Label. **NOTE:** I do not want to bind the label's content to the view model, I want to bind to the label's content because it's possible it's not only text but can also be other content.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content, ElementName=MyLabel}" />
<TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LogPanels}">
   <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MyLogPanelViewModel}">
         <Label x:Name="MyLabel" Content="Test" />
      </DataTemplate>
      <!-- Several other DataTemplates. -->
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Obviously this does not work and Visual Studio 2013 is displaying a message in the Output window:

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MyLabel'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Content; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type
>   'Object')

**Question:** What's the best way to accomplish this?

**Background info:** this is a simplified case, in the final example I'd like the Label to be a UserControl which provides it's own contextual info (menu's, buttons, etc.) to the environment outside the TabControl.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the Content of MyLabel is a databound property of MyLogPanelViewModel, let's say FooProperty.

In that case, you have to change the ContentPresenter to target the TabControl instead of the Label. ie:

```
ElementName=MyTabControl
```

And change the path to :

```
Path=SelectionItem.FooProperty
```

The result is :

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.FooProperty, ElementName=MyTabControl}" />
<TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LogPanels}">
   <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MyLogPanelViewModel}">
         <Label Content="{Binding FooProperty}" />
      </DataTemplate>
      <!-- Several other DataTemplates. -->
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I don't know the details of your implementation. Since you use dataTemplates, MyLogPanelViewModel class is probably a derived type and your LogPanels collection contains differents derived classes. The above solution will only work if you target properties of the base class of that collection.

Comment: I should've mentioned explicitly the Content property is not databound. I really want to bind to XAML based elements instead of it's data. The answer you've given is valid though given your assumption.

Comment: Okay, maybe there is something to try with the SelectedContentTemplate property instead of SelectedItem.